# Python: xpath robust to get data in table

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I want to get the data in `http://www.images.watoday.com.au/business/markets/movers` for "WHOLE MARKET TOP GAINERS" only.

My code as below:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page_gain = requests.get('http://www.images.watoday.com.au/business/markets/movers')
gain = html.fromstring(page_gain.content)
name = gain.xpath('//h2[contains(.,"Whole Market Top Gainers")]/following::a/text()')
data = gain.xpath('//h2[contains(.,"Whole Market Top Gainers")]/following::td/text()')
```

My desirable output is

```
['MEM','MEMPHASYS LTD','0.002','0.001','100.00','1,000,000','AUH','AUSTCHINA HOLDINGS','0.007','0.002','40.00','1,433,311'....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about limit to rows of the first table (`following::table[1]`) that follow the text `Whole Market Top Gainers`:

```
>>> gain = ...
>>> expr = ('//h2[contains(.,"Whole Market Top Gainers")]'
            '/following::table[1]/tbody/tr')
>>> rows = gain.xpath()
>>> [[td.text_content().strip() for td in row] for row in rows]
[['AJC', 'ACACIA COAL LTD', '0.002', '0.001rise', '100.00rise', '92,525'],
 ['MEM', 'MEMPHASYS LTD', '0.002', '0.001rise', '100.00rise', '1,000,000'],
 ['AUH', 'AUSTCHINA HOLDINGS', '0.007', '0.002rise', '40.00rise', '1,433,311'],
 ['AO1', 'ASSETOWL LIMITED', '0.100', '0.025rise', '33.33rise', '249,180'],
 ['BAS', 'BASS OIL LTD', '0.004', '0.001rise', '33.33rise', '15,390,472'],
 ['RNL', 'RISION LIMITED', '0.004', '0.001rise', '33.33rise', '6,100,812'],
 ['PAB', 'PATRYS LIMITED', '0.061', '0.013rise', '27.08rise', '86,337,514'],
 ['IQ3', 'IQ3CORP LIMITED', '0.250', '0.050rise', '25.00rise', '6,000'],
 ['SMA', 'SMARTTRANS HOLDINGS', '0.005', '0.001rise', '25.00rise', '70,000'],
 ['SEI', 'SPECIALITY METALINT', '0.035', '0.006rise', '20.69rise', '12,162,844']]
# td.text_content().strip().replace('rise', '') to remove `rise`
```